# Oracle query with conditional filters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has duplicates. Only one record for each title is marked as active or, sometimes, all records are inactive. So in case all records are inactive I need to select the record updated last and in case one is active, I need to select the active one, regardless of the latest date.

Is it possible to do in a simple query?

For example I have

```
Record_ID  Title    Status      Activity_Date
111       TEST1     Active      10/11/2020
112       TEST1     Inactive    10/11/2020
113       TEST2     Inactive    9/26/2021
114       TEST2     Inactive    4/14/2021
```

The desired result would be

```
Record_ID  Title    Status      Activity_Date
111       TEST1     Active      10/11/2020
113       TEST2     Inactive    9/26/2021
```

I used

```
SELECT * FROM TITLES t WHERE t.RECORD_ID > 100
AND t.ACTIVITY_DATE = (SELECT MAX(ACTIVITY_DATE) FROM TITLES WHERE 
RECORD_ID = t.RECORD_ID)
```

But that only take care of latest date part and returns the following:

```
Record_ID  Title    Status      Activity_Date
111       TEST1     Active      10/11/2020
112       TEST1     Inactive    10/11/2020
113       TEST2     Inactive    9/26/2021
```

Is it possible to make it conditional - if the latest date returns dups, use status?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this; read comments within code

```
SQL> with test (record_id, title, status, activity_date) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 111, 'test1', 'active'  , date '2020-10-11' from dual union all
  4     select 112, 'test1', 'inactive', date '2020-10-11' from dual union all
  5     select 113, 'test2', 'inactive', date '2021-09-26' from dual union all
  6     select 114, 'test2', 'inactive', date '2021-04-14' from dual
  7    ),
  8  temp as
  9    -- rank them - first by status, then by date in descending order
 10    (select t.*,
 11       rank() over (partition by title order by status, activity_date desc) rnk
 12     from test t
 13    )
 14  -- finally, return rows that rank the "highest"
 15  select m.record_id, m.title, m.status, m.activity_date
 16  from temp m
 17  where m.rnk = 1;

 RECORD_ID TITLE STATUS   ACTIVITY_D
---------- ----- -------- ----------
       111 test1 active   10/11/2020
       113 test2 inactive 09/26/2021

SQL>
```